# Calculating the magnitude of impedance

Tags: impedance, math, piezo

I am working on a project to model the electrical characteristics of a piezoelectric (PZT) and would like to get a sanity check to make sure I am going about it in a way that makes sense.

So I am using the [Van Dyke-Butterworth model](https://www.intechopen.com/source/html/45570/media/image2_w.jpg) for a PZT. I have measured the absolute impedance of the PZT using an impedance analyzer and am now working to fit the impedance function for the Van Dyke-Butterworth model to my data to find the value of the model components.

Where I need a check is for the steps of calculating the magnitude of the impedance.
[1](https://www.intechopen.com/source/html/45570/media/image2_w.jpg) write down Z
[2] multiply the numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator
[3] separate into real and imaginary parts and square them
[4] take the square root

I want to make sure I am not adding any terms because the steps seem to make sense but I am ending up with values extremely different for my calculated abs(Z) than from my measured abs(Z).

Am I missing something obvious? Any thoughts would be most appreciated

Comment: I found an answer to my own question over on the [math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766841/is-this-a-valid-method-of-finding-magnitude-of-complex-fraction)

Answer (score -2):

The magnitude of any complex number *z* can be found by taking the square root of *zz**, where *z** is the complex conjugate of *z*.

Comment: I realize that. However if Z has a complex denominator you do have to get it to a real denominator first, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily.